# Using later of two dates and then subtracting another date within groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,'A','X','1/3/22 12:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM','1/2/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[1,'A','X','1/4/22 12:00:00AM','1/3/22 12:00:00 AM','1/3/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[1,'A','Y','1/3/22 12:00:00AM','1/2/22 12:00:00 AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[1,'B','X','1/3/22 12:00:00AM','1/2/22 12:00:00 AM','1/3/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[2,'A','X','1/5/22 12:00:00AM','1/3/22 12:00:00 AM','1/4/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[2,'A','X','1/6/22 12:00:00AM','1/4/22 12:00:00 AM','1/5/22 12:00:00 AM']],
columns = ['ID','Category','Site','Task Completed','Access Completed', 'Upload Completed'])
```

| ID | Category | Site | Task Completed | Access Completed | Upload Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 1/3/22 12:00:00AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/2/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | A | X | 1/4/22 12:00:00AM | 1/3/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/3/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | A | Y | 1/3/22 12:00:00AM | 1/2/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | B | X | 1/3/22 12:00:00AM | 1/2/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/3/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 2 | A | X | 1/5/22 12:00:00AM | 1/3/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/4/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 2 | A | X | 1/6/22 12:00:00AM | 1/4/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/5/22 12:00:00 AM |

What I want to find is the time difference (in hours) between the later of **max** access completed date or **min** upload completed date and the first Task Completed date for every ID/Category/Site combination within the dataset.

In plain text, the logic is (the later date of (max access completed date vs min upload completed date)) - (min/first task completed date).

Based on this dataset, my intended result would look like:

| ID | Category | Site | Time Difference | First Task Completed | Max Access Date | Min Upload Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 0 | 1/3/22 12:00:00AM | 1/3/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/2/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | A | Y | 24 | 1/3/22 12:00:00AM | 1/2/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | B | X | 0 | 1/3/22 12:00:00AM | 1/2/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/3/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 2 | A | X | 24 | 1/5/22 12:00:00AM | 1/4/22 12:00:00 AM | 1/4/22 12:00:00 AM |

I know how to get the max access date minus the first task completed date:

```
out = (df
   .groupby(['ID', 'Category', 'Site'], as_index=False)
   .agg({'Task Completed': 'first', 'Access Completed': 'max'})
   .assign(**{'Time Difference': lambda d: d['Task Completed']
              .sub(d['Access Completed'])
              .dt.total_seconds().floordiv(3600)})
)
```

Which has output:

```
   ID Category Site      Task Completed Access Completed  Time Difference
0   1        A    X 2022-01-03 00:00:00       2022-01-02             24.0
1   1        A    Y 2022-01-01 01:00:00       2022-01-01              1.0
2   1        B    X 2022-01-01 01:00:00       2022-01-01              1.0
3   2        A    X 2022-01-03 00:00:00       2022-01-02             24.0
```

But I don't know how to incorporate min upload completed date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Task Completed"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["Task Completed"], format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S%p"
)
df["Access Completed"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["Access Completed"], format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p"
)
df["Upload Completed"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["Upload Completed"], format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p"
)

out = df.groupby(["ID", "Category", "Site"], as_index=False).agg(
    {
        "Task Completed": "first",
        "Access Completed": "max",
        "Upload Completed": "min",
    }
)

out["Time Difference"] = np.where(
    (out["Access Completed"] - out["Upload Completed"]) > pd.Timedelta(0),
    (out["Access Completed"] - out["Task Completed"]).abs().dt.total_seconds()
    / 3600,
    (out["Upload Completed"] - out["Task Completed"]).abs().dt.total_seconds()
    / 3600,
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

|  | ID | Category | Site | Task Completed | Access Completed | Upload Completed | Time Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A | X | 2022-01-03 12:00:00 | 2022-01-03 12:00:00 | 2022-01-02 12:00:00 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | A | Y | 2022-01-03 12:00:00 | 2022-01-02 12:00:00 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | 24 |
| 2 | 1 | B | X | 2022-01-03 12:00:00 | 2022-01-02 12:00:00 | 2022-01-03 12:00:00 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | A | X | 2022-01-05 12:00:00 | 2022-01-04 12:00:00 | 2022-01-04 12:00:00 | 24 |

Comment: if without numpy, could do `(df['First Task Completed'] - df[['Max Access Date','Min Upload Date']].max(axis=1)).dt.total_seconds() / 3600`?

Comment: @Emma Yes, `out["Time Difference"] = (out["Task Completed"] - out[["Access Completed", "Upload Completed"]].max(axis=1)).dt.total_seconds() / 3600` is possible. You can post it as your answer, I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

@Andrej Kesely's answer is already covered most part. Yet, if you would like to do this without `numpy`, you can modify the `numpy` operation part as

```py
max_time = out[["Access Completed", "Upload Completed"]].max(axis=1)
out["Time Difference"] = (out["Task Completed"] - max_time).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```